# Oracle SQL Query that Counts Various Levels of Organizational Hierarchy

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with a table (actually a view) that I created which holds three columns: year, branch, employee count.

```
create table employee_count(
  year varchar2(4),
  branch varchar2(4),
  employee_count int
);

insert into employee_count values('2014', '20', 5);
insert into employee_count values('2014', '201', 10);
insert into employee_count values('2014', '21', 5);
insert into employee_count values('2014', '2101', 10);
insert into employee_count values('2014', '2102', 5);
insert into employee_count values('2014', '22', 10);
insert into employee_count values('2014', '2201', 5);
insert into employee_count values('2014', '23', 10);
insert into employee_count values('2014', '2301', 5);
```

It is important to know that the branch column holds different levels of the organization.  For instance `20` is a department, `201` is a division and `2201` is a branch.

I am trying to construct a query that provides me with the total employee count for each branch as well as the percentage of the whole for the count.  The tricky part about this is that I want to be able to pass a parameter to denote the organization level and receive data for different levels of the organization with the results displaying sublevels.

Here is my query:

```
select sum(employee_count) as count,
  round(100 * ratio_to_report (sum(employee_count)) over()) || '%' as percent,
  substr(branch,0,length(:param) + 1) as branch,
  year
from employee_count
  where year = '2014' and branch like :param || '%'
  group by substr(branch, 0, length(:param) + 1), year
order by branch;
```

This works fine if I pass the parameter `2`, meaning the whole organization.  Then I receive my results as expected:

```
COUNT PERCENT BRANCH YEAR
15    23%     20     2014
20    31%     21     2014
15    23%     22     2014
15    23%     23     2014
```

But when I pass a particular department, say `21` as the parameter, I do not receive the counts/percentage for the levels within department `21`.

I would like to receive:

```
COUNT PERCENT BRANCH  YEAR
5     25%     21      2014
10    50%     2101    2014
5     25%     2102    2014
```

Instead I receive:

```
COUNT PERCENT BRANCH  YEAR
5     25%     21      2014
15    75%     210     2014
```

So basically I’m trying to write a query that is flexible enough to accept any level of the organization code as a parameter and then return the count/percentage for each level below.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or let me know if this is even possible?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/27617/7)

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
select sum(employee_count) as count,
round(100 * ratio_to_report (sum(employee_count)) over()) || '%' as percent,
branch as branch,
year
from employee_count
where year = '2014' and branch like '21%'
group by branch, year
order by branch;
```

Comment: Thanks! That gets the job done for the second requirement, but will not provide the expected result for the first (entire organization so using '2').  I'm starting to wonder if this is not possible since my expectations for each result set seem to differ.  I'm starting to think this might be two queries.

Comment: or, always make the query use the department (2-char) that get passed to it??

Comment: If you notice the first expected result, it only contains the departments.  The second expected result contains everything within the department (division and branch).  I'm trying to make the query pull double duty, when I probably shouldn't be.